# Callback after state update in Reducer of Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

**Problem:** I want to write some code more efficiently.
Below you will find my full code example of a Redux Toolkit slice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { setCookie } from '../../utils/storageHandler';

const initialState = {
  name: null,
  age: null
}

const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'formSlice',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setName(state, action) {
      state.name = action.payload;
      setCookie('name', action.payload);
    },
    setAge(state, action) {
      state.age = action.payload;
      setCookie('age', action.payload);
      
    }
  }
});

export const { setName, setAge,  } =
  formSlice.actions;

export default formSlice.reducer;
```

I do not want to write **setCookie(name, value)** each time I run a reducer.
Rather I want to write it once and call it each time a reducer function has been called.

I would pass a payload of:

```
{type: string, value: string}
```

and then run a callback from every reducer and call the **setCookie(...)** function as follows:

```
setCookie(action.payload.type, action.payload.value)
```

Ideally I would write this code within the slice as so

```
const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'formSlice',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setName(state, action) {
      state.name = action.payload;
    },
    setAge(state, action) {
      state.age = action.payload;
    }
  },
  callback(action) {
    setCookie(action.payload.type, action.payload.value)
  }
});
```

Is there a way of achieving this?
Or maybe an another way of thinking?

My main goal is to have form values stored within cookies, so as to prefill the registration form each time a customer visits it.
There is no authentication.
I will not write cookie storage logic within a component!

Thank you for your attention and I wish you a pleasant day :)

Comment: I think you need to try [createListenerMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware). This may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into passing a middleware function? You can create your own custom middleware like this

```
const saveForm = (api: MiddlewareAPI) => (next) => (action) => {
    if (action.type === 'setName') { ... }
    if (action.type === 'setAge') { ... }

    return next(action);
}
```

and then concat it to the default

```
const store = configureStore({
   reducer: rootReducer,
   middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(saveForm),
})
```

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.
Although I am tempted to move this cookie setting logic completely to a different file.

I can access state anywhere with: const state = useSelector((state: RootState) => state); 

Everytime state changes this variable changes. 
I could do less uncoupled code going this way.
I will see and let you know, thank you a lot :)